# how to post dictionary and array server using post mathods

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, ios8.1

How to post json server i am trying to add  dictionary and post data but not getting write response

{"type":"general",
"noteText":[{"lineNo":"1","lineText":"patient admited"}]}

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

```
NSString *Str = @"general";
  NSString *St2r = @"Yogesh";
NSString *Str1 = @"1";
```

NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

```
NSDictionary *tempDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               Str1, @"lineNo",
                             St2r, @"lineText",
                                nil];
[tempArray addObject:tempDictionary];

NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:tempArray,@"noteText", nil];
NSError *error;

NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tempDict options:0 error:&error];
```

//[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"type\":\"%@\"}",Str];
   // NSLog(@"Request: %@", jsonRequest);

```
NSURL *url7 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URl"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url7];
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];


NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)

{

    if(error == nil)
    {
        NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
    }

}];
```

Comment: post some code how are you doing this????

Comment: Where is the `[postDataTask resume];` ? Add it at the end of your dataTaskWithRequest.

Comment: I'm also confused with these lines: `[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];` and `[request setHTTPBody: requestData];` Why are you using requestData? `[request setHTTPBody:postData];`is enough and then add the **postData** content-length to the request:

Comment: You should use AFNetworking library: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Answer (score 0):

Consider using AFNetworking perhaps?

You can download the code from [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Use the following code as sample for a post call to server.

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```